# Coded UI- Control switch during WaitForCondition

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to figure why my Row get switch when I call the WaitForCondition

The way I the isStatusDone is define is like:

```
        static int a = 0;
    private static bool isStatusDone(UITestControl control) {
        WinRow row = (WinRow)control;
        AbstractedGUI.clickOnMainWindow("Refresh");

        WinCell attentionCell = new WinCell(row);
        attentionCell.SearchProperties[WinCell.PropertyNames.Value] = "Attention";
        Debug.WriteLine(a + row.FriendlyName  +  " " + System.DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
        a++;
        return attentionCell.Exists;
    }
```

Does anyone have any idea why the row switch?

The output is:

Test Name:  TestMethod

Test Outcome:   Passed

Result StandardOutput:

Debug Trace:

0MarginRecordMessage row 1 11:54:58 AM

1MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:03 AM

2MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:08 AM

3MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:13 AM

4MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:18 AM

5MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:23 AM

6MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:28 AM

7MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:33 AM

8MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:38 AM

9MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:44 AM

10MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:49 AM

11MarginRecordMessage row 0 11:55:54 AM

Comment: I figure out that my refresh is affecting it.. so now i gotta figure out to grab the correct row everytime i refresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that I need to add the line before I call this

control.SearchProperties[WinRow.PropertyName.Name] = row.name

Cause that will set the search properties to what I was looking for originally and so when it refreshes it still have that property to search